# RedirectTo a tab in the same aspx page using a case statement

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, tabs

I have a site where there are 5 tabs on one page. To get the "Next" and "Back" buttons to work navigating between the tabs, I am using an enum for the tab references and using RedirectTo in a case statement to navigate between the tabs. The tabs' URLs are #WhatHappened, etc. This is not working, what happens is that the URL changes to reflect the new address but the old tab is active and the data is gone from the tab even though I am using a function to do a save, which is why I am not using javascript for this.

Any ideas would be great.

Code in the save function...

```
 protected void SaveEventDetails(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isSubmitted = false;
            PageLocation pageLocation = (PageLocation)Session["pageLocation"];

            switch (e.CommandName)
            {

                case "BACK":
                    if (_eventID == 0)
                    {
                        Save(false, Mode.Edit, Status.Save);
                        RedirectTo(pageLocation - 1);
                    }
                    else
                        Update(_eventID, false, Status.Save);
                        RedirectTo(pageLocation - 1);
                    break;
                case "NEXT":
                    if (_eventID == 0)
                    {
                        Save(false, Mode.Edit, Status.Save);
                        RedirectTo(pageLocation + 1);
                    }
                    else
                        Update(_eventID, false, Status.Save);
                    RedirectTo(pageLocation + 1);
                    break;
```

Code in the redirect to function...

```
public void RedirectTo(PageLocation pageLocation)
        {
            switch (pageLocation)
            {
                case PageLocation.ApprovalActions:
                    Response.Redirect("#tabInvestigatorAction");
                    break;
                case PageLocation.WhoWasInvolved:
                    Response.Redirect("#tabInvolved");
                    break;
                case PageLocation.Questions:
                    Response.Redirect("#tabQuestions");
                    break;
                case PageLocation.InvestigatorComments:
                    Response.Redirect("#tabNotes");
                    break;
                case PageLocation.AttachmentsAndComments:
                    Response.Redirect("tabAttachmentsComments");
                    break;
                default:
                    Response.Redirect("#tabWhatHappened");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

ENUM Code...

```
public enum PageLocation
    {
        WhatHappend = 1,
        Questions,
        WhoWasInvolved,
        AttachmentsAndComments,
        InvestigatorComments,
        ApprovalActions,
    }
```

ASPX page code...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBack" CommandName="BACK" OnCommand="SaveEventDetails" runat="server" class="buttonColor" Text="Back" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnNext" CommandName="NEXT" OnCommand="SaveEventDetails" runat="server" class="buttonColor" Style="margin-right: 30px;" Text="Next" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ui for tabs and then use tab id in url to go to the tab.

Also if you are using server tab control, make sure the client id is same as you are providing in url